# Advanced usage of the `reduce` method

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I just recently learned `reduce`s functionality. It's been extremely useful. Recently I used it on an array of strings to automatically produce a series of outputs for me. I want to turn something like:

```
miscArray = ["dog", "cat", "hamster"]
```

into something like:

```
miscString =
"\nYou have a dog.
\nYou have a cat.
\nYou have a hamster."
```

However, reduce doesn't apply it's function to the first iteration of an array. If my code looks something like this:

```
function outputString(x,y){
  return x+"\nYou have a "+y+".";
}

miscArray = ["dog", "cat", "hamster"]

alert(miscArray.reduce(outputString));
```

I end up getting something like this:

```
"dog
\nYou have a cat.
\nYou have a hamster."
```

As a workaround, I've been using an empty string in the start of my array like so : `miscArrray = ["","dog", "cat", "hamster"]`. However, using a workaround just means that I don't know how to do things right. I'm considering just making my own variant of the `reduce()` method, but if there's a right/better way to do it. I'd rather do it that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There surely is:

you need to specify the initial value for the accumulator. In your case it is `''` (an empty string).

```
function outputString(x,y){
  return x+"\nYou have a "+y+".";
}

miscArray = ["dog", "cat", "hamster"]

alert(miscArray.reduce(outputString, ''));
```

When the initial value for the accumulator is set it is passed as the first argument on the first iteration, together with the first array item as a second parameter, and so on.

It actually is a good habit to **ALWAYS** explicitly set the accumulator, since then the typing of the expression becomes much more obvious and clear.

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I needed. Thanks! I'll certainly use it in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Do not use `reduce` in this case.  Use the following:

```
miscArray.map(x => "\nYou have a "+ x +".").join("")
```

Comment: One could say technically, that `join` is a reduce operation

Comment: @Phil `map` is also a reduce operation :-) `Array.prototype.reduce` is enough to express every other array operation.

Comment: You meant `.join("")`, right? `.join()` is equivalent to `.join(",")`

Comment: I was going to say, mine were returning with commas. This works as well. Thanks!

Comment: @zerkms `map` is a structure preserving operation. It can be derived from reduce but it doesn't modify the structure of the data it operates on.

Comment: @ftor yes. Not sure I'm following though.

Comment: @zerkms _"map is also a reduce operation"_ This is misleading. `map` can be derived from `reduce` yes, because it is less generalized. But it merely transforms values, not structures. `map` is not a reduce operation.